# Removing unwanted characters in a list in tkinter, while using the random module

Tags: python, tkinter, random

I made a character randomizer in tkinter that takes the user entry, then feeds it through random.shuffle with a button, then prints it on a LabelFrame, also saving it to a text file. I don't know where/how I would insert code to remove the spaces, commas and brackets. I've searched other questions but to no avail, I can't seem to implement other answers to my specific problem.

Here is some example code, thanks a bunch! I didn't want to flood the screen with all the code, this is my first post here, but if more is needed then I could just copy-paste it all.

```
e = Entry(root, bd=3, bg='white')
e.pack(fill=X, pady=3, padx=3)

def get_answer():
    answer = list((e.get()))
    global widget
    widget = LabelFrame(frame2, text='Please 
    click Randomize', bd=0, width=500, 
    height=300, bg='white', font=150)
    widget.pack(padx=3)
    file_create = open('text.txt', 'w+', 
    encoding='utf-8')
    for i in range(1):
        random.shuffle(answer)
        file_create.write(str(answer))

    file_create.close()
    button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

def file_opener():
    global m
    widget.destroy()
    f = open('text.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    m = LabelFrame(frame2, width=500, 
    height=300, bd=0, bg='white', font=150, 
    text=f.read())
    m.pack(expand=TRUE)
    f.close()
    button_3.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
```

Comment: You want to remove those unwanted characters before shuffling?

Comment: And why do you have this loop: "for i in range(1):"

Comment: " I don't know where/how I would insert code to remove the spaces, commas and brackets." Well, do you want them to be in the list that gets shuffled? Where in the code do you first get the text, and where in the code do you shuffle the list? Kinda narrows it down, doesn't it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be simply a matter of thinking clearly, not about some unknown programming technique / library functionality / etc.

Comment: I want them removed after the shuffle, so what I see on the labelframe and in the text document, typing the word hello, is not ['h', 'l', 'o', 'l', 'e'] but hlole.

Comment: Thanks for asking about the loop, I had forgotten to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove those characters before showing, you can do that just here `str(answer)`.

And you can do this basicaly;

for example to remove commas and dots:

```
str(answer).replace(",", "").replace(".", "")
```

or you have a lot characters that needs to remove you can go this way;

```
characters_to_remove = "!()@"
pattern = "[" + characters_to_remove + "]"
new_answer = re.sub(pattern, "", str(answer))
```

then you can use new_answer instead of answer.

Edited: Thanks for warning of @qBen_Plays , strip is more usable option to make that.

```
str(answer).strip("[], ")
```

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong, but cant they just use ``str(answer).strip("[], ")`` for an easy one-liner? They only wanted to remove commas, brackets, and spaces after all.

Comment: You are totally right, strip would be more usable for multiple characters.

Comment: When I try to use these methods, it gives the error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: You are using after str(answer) right? Like this: `file_create.write(str(answer).strip("[], "))` If it's right that is weird because str means string already. Where do you read your random text? You can try this function there.

Comment: And just for additional information you can make a string from list like: `stringfromlist = ' '.join(map(str, yourlist))`. But in your case I suggest to use strip method just before show your text or while adding a text to list.

Comment: Okay, I placed it correctly and it partially works, if I type in ga, then it will return a', 'g. The brackets are gone, and one ', but the comma will not be removed, nor the second '. The random text is just put onto a LabelFrame and txt doc.Thanks so much btw, sorry if what I'm asking is really obvious.

Comment: Ah, and I put file_create.write(str(answer).strip("[],' "))

Comment: I'm glad if I could help, nothing obvious if we don't know :) BTW if my answer was a correct one you can accept it for future readers.

Comment: If your string turned like  ['h', 'l', 'o', 'l', 'e']  that means you need to list to string to use strip correctly and to get rid of all space you need to replace method too beside strip. So you can use this line instead of `str(answer)` this one: `' '.join(map(str, answer)).strip(" [],' ").replace(" ","")`